# Equality-constrained optimization problem

Tags: analysis, optimization

I'm trying to prove that the plane shown in the picture below is bounded. I found that the norm of $x$ is greater than or equal to $72/3$ and so it is bounded. Would my reasoning be correct?

> Consider the equality-constrained optimization problem
> $$ \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^3} - x_1 x_2 x_3 \quad \text{such that} \quad x_1 + 2 x_2 + 2 x_3 = 72.$$
> Can you guarantee that a global minimizer exists? Give reasons for your answer.

Comment: The equation describes a 2-dimensional plane in three-space. How can it be bounded? Surely there is more to this problem you are not telling us.

Comment: I added the whole question now

Comment: But don't necessarily worry about a. I'm a bit confused if the constraint is bounded or not. I did some working out and found that it is, but as you said it is a plane and so it can't be bounded.

Comment: The equation describes an unbounded set, but that is less relevant for your problem. More relevant is whether the objective function is bounded on that set or not, and that is a different question.

Comment: Is the "picture below" in a pending status ?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek How would we go about doing that then? Would we have to substitute the constraint into the objective function?

Comment: @JeanMarie The picture should be visible

Comment: Sorry, it isn't visible.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird! I'll try reuploading the pic

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Use Lagrange multipliers.